# In 22.04 'Activities' menu/grid, cannot remove icon

Tags: uninstall, desktop-icons, activities-overview

Somehow, an icon has been added to the desktop called 'Sysinfo'.  I have researched this extensively and cannot find any way to delete this icon.  From a command line, there appears no '[Ss]ysinfo' file on my system.  How can I remove it?   Thanks.
[image]